# How to parse xml string element?

Tags: c#, xml

In C#, I have an xml string named `inputXmlString` like this:

```
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:dd="clr-namespace:DiagramDesigner;assembly=GUI">
              <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                  <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFAFBE9" Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF00FFFF" Offset="1" />
                  </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
              </Setter.Value>
<TextBox Background="#00FFFFFF" Foreground="#FF000000" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Thread</TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Now I want to get the text of the `TextBox` element. For that I tried this method:

```
XElement inputElement = XElement.Parse(inputXmlString);
XElement textbox = inputElement.Element("TextBox");
string result = textbox.Value;
```

But the `textbox` element comes as null here. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a namespace on your element, you need to specify it:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation";
XElement textbox = inputElement.Element(ns + "TextBox");
```